# Discrete wavelet transform with complex shannon wavelet

Tags: wavelet-analysis

The complex Shannon function is defined as:

[image]

It seems that Mathematica doesn't support the complex Shannon transform although it supports the real Shannon function. I need the complex Shannon function to run a discrete wavelet transform.
Can I define a new wavelet exactly like the equation for complex Shannon?

Comment: Have a look here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningYourOwnWavelet.html

Answer (score 2):

$\color{red}{\text{In different definitions,}}$

$\color{red}{\text{there may be horizontal axis scaling, vertical axis scaling, horizontal axis shift.}}$

$\color{red}{\text{but you should make sure the shapes are consistent.}}$

## Mathematica

```
mySincFunction[x_] := If[x == 0, 1, Sin[Pi x]/(Pi x)];
shanwavf[LB_, UB_, N_, FB_, FC_] := 
 Module[{XRange, psi}, XRange = Range[LB, UB, (UB - LB)/(N - 1)];
  psi = Table[(FB^0.5)*(mySincFunction[FB X]*Exp[2 I Pi FC X]), {X, 
     XRange}];
  {psi, XRange}]
{psi, x} = shanwavf[-20, 20, 1000, 1, 1.5];

GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, Re[psi]}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Complex Shannon Wavelet - Real Part", 
   AxesLabel -> {"X", "Real Part"}, PlotRange -> Full], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, Im[psi]}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Complex Shannon Wavelet - Imaginary Part", 
   AxesLabel -> {"X", "Imaginary Part"}, PlotRange -> Full]}]
```

[image]

now [DefiningYourOwnWavelet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningYourOwnWavelet.html). **I'm not sure whether the below code is true.**

```
ComplexShannonWavelet[LB_, UB_, N_, FB_, FC_]["WaveletQ"] := True;
ComplexShannonWavelet[LB_, UB_, N_, FB_, FC_]["OrthogonalQ"] := True
ComplexShannonWavelet[LB_, UB_, N_, FB_, FC_]["PrimalLowpass", 
   prec_ : MachinePrecision] := 
  Module[{psi, X}, {psi, X} = shanwavf[LB, UB, N, FB, FC]; psi];


yourImage = Import["ExampleData/photo.jpg"]
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[yourImage, ComplexShannonWavelet[-20, 20, 100, 1, 1.5], 2]
```

## MATLAB

Why don't you use [`shanwavf`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/shanwavf.html) in MATLAB, which seems more practical.

```matlab
fb = 1;
fc = 1.5;
lb = -20; 
ub = 20; 
n = 1000;
[psi,x] = shanwavf(lb,ub,n,fb,fc);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,real(psi))
title('Complex Shannon Wavelet')
xlabel('Real Part')
grid on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,imag(psi))
xlabel('Imaginary Part')
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: if i want cwt(Continuous wavelet transform) Instead of dwt i need fourier factor and fourier transform so how can this be defined for Shannon?