# Continuous wavelet transform with complex shannon wavelet

Tags: wavelet-analysis

The complex Shannon function is defined as:
[image]

It seems that Mathematica doesn't support the complex Shannon transform although it supports the real Shannon function. I need the complex Shannon function to run a continuous wavelet transform. Can I define a new wavelet exactly like the equation for complex Shannon?

Comment: Is this related to: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288318/discrete-wavelet-transform-with-complex-shannon-wavelet

Comment: my question is about Continuous wavelet transform with complex shannon wavelet not discrete wavelet transform